# String appearing for a short of time

Tags: java, swing, label

I created a string and i wanted it to appear to like 10 seconds and disappear again 
how can you do that using java ? 
Im using swing and i want apply this on a label
Sorry for not specifying , i'm still new to java

Comment: You will need to provide **a lot** more context.

Comment: -1 Where? did you try something? please provide more details

Comment: Please add context.  Applet?  HTML?  Swing?  AWT?  What do you have so far?

Answer (score 4):

If this is Swing, then use a Swing Timer. Set it to non-repeating, and call its constructor with the time in milliseconds that you'd like to show the String, here 10 x 1000. You could show the text in a JLabel by calling setText("your string") on the JLabel first and then call setText("") again on the JLabel from within the timer's ActionListener's actionPerformed method.

If this is not Swing, and even if it is, you need to provide a lot more detail for your problem to be fully solvable here.

Comment: -1 you don t have enough details + even if it is swing, the answer is incomplete

Comment: @JohnJohn: And how do you decide on what constitutes a "complete" answer? Isn't it better to nudge the OP in the correct direction and leave a bit for them to discover rather than post teh codez for them to copy? This is particularly true when the OP hasn't put much effort into formulating the question itself.